# MATLAB - Dados são perdidos ao encerrar o laço FOR

Tags: for, matlab

Estou tendo problemas com um laço de repetição que conta os
pixels brancos de um pedaço de uma imagem e armazena a posição
x e y do pedaço e o total de pixels brancos. 
Quando imprimo os valores dentro do laço funciona, mas imediatamente após o laço os três arrays estão com os valores zerados.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

**Código:**

```
y = zeros(altura*largura);
x = zeros(altura*largura);
v = zeros(altura*largura);


for j=0:altura-1
    for k=0:largura-1

        pedaco = f8(j*40+1 : j*40+40, k*40+1 : k*40+40); %binary piece
        pedac = im2uint8(pedaco);
        totalBrancos = sum(sum(pedac)); %sum white pixels

        pos = altura*j+k+1;

        y(pos) = j;
        x(pos) = k;
        v(pos) = totalBrancos;

        disp(y(pos)); %works
        disp(x(pos)); %works
        disp(v(pos)); %works

    end
end  

disp(y); %all zeros
disp(x); %all zeros
disp(v); %all zeros
```

Comment: O código é somente isso mesmo?

Comment: Este trecho de código faz parte de um codigo maior..
mas a parte que faz o que mencionei "um laço de repetição que conta os pixels brancos de um pedaço de uma imagem e armazena a posição x e y do pedaço e o total de pixels brancos", está todo aí.

Comment: estranho, não faz sentido os dados estarem zerados ao sair do loop, tem certeza que não tem mais nada de código ?

Comment: exatamente @ederwander. Não entendo por que isso acontece. 
Como disse antes, a parte que faz a contagem dos pixels brancos e armazena as posições x e y e o total, é essa.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que não são todos zeros.

Nas três primeiras linhas, tente fazer assim:

```
y = zeros(altura*largura,1);
x = zeros(altura*largura,1);
v = zeros(altura*largura,1);
```

E então teste o programa de novo

Answer (score 0):

A resposta dada pelo [Ataíde](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217914/88991) --alias, acho que nem todos os elementos serão zero também-- funciona para caso você queira colocar todos os pontos em uma linha, caso a intencão seja deixar todos os pontos em uma matriz, o código muda em alguns pontos:

Na declaracão:

```
y = zeros(altura,largura);
x = zeros(altura,largura);
v = zeros(altura,largura);
```

Dentro do loop:

```
    y(j+1,k+1) = j;
    x(j+1,k+1) = k;
    v(j+1,k+1) = totalBrancos;

    disp(y(j+1,k+1)); %works
```

Note que neste caso, as matrizes `y` e `x` acabam por ficar com o valor do seu respectivo índice subtraindo 1.